# Powershell Regex to find number pattern

Tags: regex, powershell

Heyho,

I'm pretty new to using regex, and I can't seem to find the right regex to match a pattern like this:

> 1000.00
>
> 2093.09
>
> ####.##

the numbers could be anything but the digits are always 4 before the dot and 2 after.
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 4):

Use `[0-9]` to describe a single digit 0 through 9, then a bounded quantifier `{N}` to specify how many:

```
[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}
```

PowerShell's regex operators (`-match`, `-notmatch`, `-replace`, `-split`) apply *partial matching* by default, so make sure you anchor your pattern with `\b` (word boundary) or `^`/`$` (start of string, end of string):

```
'2093.09' -match '^[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}$'
# or
'The number is 1234.56 or thereabout' -match '\b[0-9]{4}\.[0-9]{2}\b'
```